# Forward incoming mail to any domain not specified in relay_domains

Tags: postfix

we have an internal test-server that uses real, live mail addresses to send out status mails sometimes. We don't want these mails to end up with our users but for different reasons we can't use a catch_all solution and we only have the one available mail server. What we need is a way to forward incoming mail from any domain not specified in relay_domains to a specified mailbox.

Comment: what MTA are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming mails to a specific user then you can add those guys to the relayed domains and set up a forwarding to each of them.

Comment: Thing is that the number of possible email domains is too large and all are unknown to us. So instead, we need to forward all mails, except for all mails to specific domains.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can use recipient_canonical_maps.

Have a look here: http://www.postfix.org/rewrite.html

If there is no simply way adding relay domains negated into that map, you can build a large regular expression which contains all your relay domains negated to put into a special mailbox.